# Graphs in Prolog (Graphs ,Tree)

Tags: tree, prolog, graph-theory

I have a small problem with Prolog. I don't really understand this language.
I have to check if the graph is a tree and I have no idea how can I do this.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Recurse down your structure. Have you tried anything? How far does your understanding of the language reach?

Comment: This is not a question that can be meaningfully answered. The only answer to your current question is, "Yes, I have some ideas". You can improve your question by reading ["how to ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We need more information to help you. And you need to learn about this site,  Please get informed how this site works by reading [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Well...first, you want to define "tree". Off the top of my head, a tree is a *directed graph*. And you need a way to represent a directed graph in Prolog. Once such way would be something like this:

```
%
% a predicate to define your nodes. Not truly necessary,
% but you might find it useful for carrying payload around.
%
node(X [, payload] ).

%
% says that an edge run from node X to node Y.
% you also might want to carry payload here (for
% instance, your edges might have some weight/cost associated with
% them, such as distance, price, etc.
%
edge(X,Y [, payload] ). % says that an edge runs from node X to node Y.
```

And a *tree* has the following following properties:

- Each node in a tree has, at most, a single parent node (cardinality is zero-or-one), to which it is connected via a single inbound edge (implying that a child node does not know who its parent is).
- Each node in a tree has zero or more child nodes (cardinality is zero-to-many), each of which is connected via a single outbound edge (implying that each node knows who its children are).
- A tree has a a single root node, one without a parent (e.g., no inbound edges). If your directed graph has multiple root nodes, it is a *forest* (of trees).
- Nodes with no children (outbound edges) are leaf nodes.

This leads to a recursive definition of a tree: each node in a tree can be looked at as being a tree on its own, right? That should lead you to a descriptive solution (in Prolog).

Give it a try, show us some sample code and we can give you some help.